# position span inline-blocks at the bottom of a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello I'm developing a website header with bootstrap 3 which consists of 4 divs.
Each of those 4 divs has 2 nested divs inside.
In the first nested div exist 2 inline block spans, with different fonts and font-sizes.

Imagine one of the 4 initial divs, what I would like to achieve is something this:

```
___________________________________
|                                 |
|                                 |
|        180,00€   Total          |
|---------------------------------|
|     for the last 30 days        |
|                                 |
|_________________________________|
```

As you can see inside each of the 4 divs something like the above will exist.
180,00€ and total are 2 span inline-blocks.
I'd like the upper text to be aligned at the bottom and the lower text to be aligned at the top.

You may see a working demo here: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Wfm2w/4/)

HTML:

```
<div class="row stats-row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 stat"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 stat"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 stat"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 stat">
        <div class="data">
            <span class="data-num">81,00€</span>
            <span class="num-desc">total</span>         
        </div>
        <div class="data-desc">last 30 days</div>       
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row.stats-row {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px rgba(218, 227, 233, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px rgba(218, 227, 233, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px rgba(218, 227, 233, 0.5);
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px !important;
}

.row.stats-row .stat {
    border-right: 1px solid #dae3e9;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dae3e9;
    height: 80px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 0px rgba(218, 227, 233, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 0px rgba(218, 227, 233, 0.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 0px rgba(218, 227, 233, 0.5);
}
/* EDIT BELLOW */

.stats-row .stat .data{
    text-align: center;
    height: 50%;
}
.stats-row .stat .data-desc{
    text-align:center;
    height:50%;
    color:#777; 
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif, Arial;
}
.stats-row .stat .data > span{
    display: inline-block;
    height:100%;
    line-height:100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
.stats-row .stat .data .data-num{
    margin-right:20px;
    color: #32a0ee;
    font-size: 25px;
}
.stats-row .stat .data .num-desc{
    color: #29323a;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
}
#monthGraphs .portlet-header h3{
    text-align:center;
}
.graph{
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Added spans in he .data-desc section and managed this

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rf6p6/1/)

**Adjusted HTML section**

```
<div class="data-desc"><span>over the last</span><span>30 days</span></div>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.row.stats-row {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px rgba(218, 227, 233, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px rgba(218, 227, 233, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px rgba(218, 227, 233, 0.5);
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px !important;
}

.row.stats-row .stat {
    border-right: 1px solid #dae3e9;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dae3e9;
    height: 80px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 0px rgba(218, 227, 233, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 0px rgba(218, 227, 233, 0.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 0px rgba(218, 227, 233, 0.5);
}
/* EDIT BELLOW */

.stats-row .stat .data{
    height: 50%;
}
.stats-row .stat .data-desc span{
    height:50%;
    color:#777; 
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif, Arial;
}
.stats-row .stat .data > span{
   //display: inline-block;
    height:100%;
    line-height:100%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.stats-row .stat .data .data-num{
    color: #32a0ee;
    font-size: 25px;
}
.stats-row .stat .data .num-desc{
    color: #29323a;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
}
/* EDIT BELLOW */

.stats-row .stat .data{
    overflow: hidden; /* quick clearfix */
}

.data span,
.data-desc span{
  width:50%;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
}

.data span:last-child,
.data-desc span:last-child{
  text-align:left;
    padding-left:16px;
}
```

Adding classes to the spans would avoid the need to use `last-child` and the line-heights could use tweaking. **Frankly, it might just be easier to use a table. :)**

Answer (score 0):

if i understand the question right. try adding this at the bottom of your css

```
.data-num{
    padding-top:15px;
}
```